# Why does TryParseExact require CultureInfo if I specify the exact structure?

Tags: c#, datetime, .net-4.0, cultureinfo

Looking at

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt",
                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 0, out dateValue)
```

I supplied the exact structure to look for :  `M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt`

**Question**

If so , Why should I need to specify `CultureInfo` also ?

Comment: Short version: You didn't specify `/` or `:`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, month names can be localized, too. And perhaps in some exotic cultures the years are counted in a different way as well.

EDIT:
Example:

```
string x = "Montag, 2. April 2012";
DateTime dt1, dt2;
bool r1 = DateTime.TryParseExact(x, "D", new CultureInfo("de-DE"), 0, out dt1);
bool r2 = DateTime.TryParseExact(x, "D", new CultureInfo("en-US"), 0, out dt2);
```

(`r1 == true`, `r2 == false`).

Or, other way round:

```
string y = "Monday, April 02, 2012";
DateTime dt3, dt3;
bool r3 = DateTime.TryParseExact(y, "D", new CultureInfo("de-DE"), 0, out dt3);
bool r4 = DateTime.TryParseExact(y, "D", new CultureInfo("en-US"), 0, out dt4);
```

(`r3 == false`, `r2 == true`).

Comment: it's German (`de-DE`) for Monday (but perhaps you could share the image with us?)

Comment: if montag is monday so what is `2.` ?

Comment: @Royi: the number of day in the month.

Answer (score 4):

Because the format string is not literal. For example you used "/" and ":" but for the input string is required to use the [date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator) and [time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#timeSeparator) separators supplied by the `CultureInfo`.

Imagine this format string: M/d/yyyy
These inputs are all valid:

- 04/02/2012 (for invariant culture, USA);
- 04.02.2012 (for Finland)
- 04-02-2012 (for Morocco)

Moreover the simple "M" specifier can be [1..12] or [1..13], depending on the calendar itself (see MSDN).

As "candle on the cake" the function is generic so you may require in the format string a localized (or country dependant) value (think about weekday names or the year specified, for example, in Chinese or in Japanese).

Comment: I dont understand can you please explain ?

Comment: the string "M/d/yyyy" is a format specifier for "4/2/2012" in en-US culture but is a valid input, for example, "4-2-2012" for Arabic culture too. The "/" character means "the default date separator for the given culture". Anyway I updated the answer with an example.

Comment: no...it's just a _format_, it'll replace "/" with its actual value according with the given culture. If it must be exact you have to escape.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell it the culture, because if you pass it the format dd-mmm-yyyy
then pass in 01/05/2012

In english that might be 01-May-2012

But in another culture it would be 01-Mai-2012